# Adding JavaScript to PHP form throws Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel

I had to make a php form for a class assignment. We then had to alter the form using another language to make it more functional.

I decided to add JavaScript to it so the user could add multiple parts. After I added the JavaScript I now get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Here is the form:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
@for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
<input type="number" name="part_number" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
<input type="submit" value="Add Part" />
@endfor
<input type="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" />
<input type="text" name="shippingaddress" placeholder="Shipping Address" />
<input type="text" name="project_id" placeholder="Project Id" />
<input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="User Id" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Requests" />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about `JavaScript` instead, `Laravel` uses `POST` method to submit a form by default and `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` occurs when you declared a route in your application (basically in `routes.php` file) using one method (GET, POST, DELETE etc) but using a different method to submit the form.

Make sure your route for the form submission and the method used in form are same. If you don't explicitly mention a method in the form then it will be `POST` by default and you may use a differnt method using something like this:

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'action' => 'Controller@method', 'method' => 'GET') ) }}
```

Or something like this:

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'route' => 'routename', 'method' => 'GET') ) }}
```

Or something like this:

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'url' => 'your/url', 'method' => 'GET') ) }}
```

To be more clear, If you have declared a route using something like this:

```
Route::get(...);
```

Then use `GET` method in the form or if something else then use that method but if you used `post()` then you don't need to use any method in your form. Check more on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form).

Also your loop is incorrect, your inputs has same name so last one will override the previous ones and you'll get only one input per name, use the array notation in name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any javascript in your form, but regardless Javascript alone won't cause this.  This error is saying, "You're trying to hit a route with an incorrect HTTP method"  Basically you're trying to POST to a route that only allows GET access.

By default, Laravel forms will use POST.  You can try changing the method on the form to GET:

```
{{ Form::open([ 'method' => 'GET' ]) }}
```

But really it should be whatever you have defined in your `app/routes.php` file for the route you're trying to access.

As an aside, these inputs will overwrite one-another when the form is actually submitted since they will have a name clash when repeated in your for loop:

```
<input type="number" name="part_number" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
```

Consider making them submit an array instead:

```
<input type="number" name="part_number[]" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage[]" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
```